# Find the smallest of the largest from groups without subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have the following schema:

```
BUDGETS
-------
DEPT (string)
ITEM (string)
BUDGET (integer)
```

I want to find the cost of the cheapest item that's the most expensive of the department without any subqueries. Is that possible?

I have:

```
with max_per_dept as
(select dept, max(budget) as budget
from budgets
group by dept)
select min(budget) from max_per_dept;
```

Comment: Why the restriction on sub-queries? A solution with sub-queries may well be the best solution to your problem.

Comment: It's retrofitting requirements to an old system.

Comment: Then please name your old system. It may not have window functions, yet.

Comment: The application, not the DBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the item that is the cheapest "most expensive" item for any department.

One method uses `order by`:

```
select b.*
from budgets b
order by max(budget) over (partition by dept) asc,
         dept,
         budget desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```